# Why am I getting 404 Bad Gate Way Error?

Tags: apache, servlets, struts2, oracle10g, tomcat7

I am doing a struts 2 program and I have a form like below. I set the value of 'listData' using jquery and it will be a long JSON string and may have 3184 or more characters.

```
<s:form action="myAction" method="post" id="hiddenForm">
    <s:hidden name="listData" />
</s:form>
```

On submitting the form I am getting below error :

HTTP Status 404 - /appNameerror/HTTP_BAD_GATEWAY.html.var

Any idea why is it happening ?

**For info :** I am converting a big form into json string and setting the value to hidden form and submitting. If I submit 10 rows of data (~3184 char json), 7 rows are getting saved after parsing json string and remaining 3 may not save and I get above error. If I submit 5 rows of data. Everything works fine and I won't get any error.

**Environment :** I am using Apache as web-server and Tomcat 7.x is acting as application server. Application is deployed in tomcat. All the request from the client are received by web-server and will be redirected to the tomcat server.

Answer (score 0):

If this is regard the size request which is send back to server you can set the `maxParameterCount`, and `maxPostSize` of tomcat connector in `web.xml`. This can be find at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html

Also it is possible that depending the configuration the Apache drop this request. You need to fix some parameters there which could be `post_max_size`. (There may be other parameters which needs to be set)